# How to eliminate brackets from caption for subfigures in latex?

Tags: floats, captions, subfig

The problem I have is that when I compile the image caption is displayed with brackets "[fig caption]".......................................................................................................................................

```
 \documentclass{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{booktabs} % For professional looking tables
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    %\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    %\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{slashbox}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    %\usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{bigstrut}
    \usepackage{algorithmicx}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    \usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \modulolinenumbers[5]
    \journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}



\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{figure}
         \subfigure[]{ \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{graph1}
            } 
             \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{graph2}%
             }
              \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{graph3}}%
\caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to your example code, I get the following error message: "! Undefined control sequence. \subfigure" If you get an error message, do not look at the outpu. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: To resolve this, replace `\subfigure` with `\subfloat`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're loading the `caption` package, I'd go with the machinery of the highly-compatible `subcaption` package rather than with that of the only-somewhat-compatible `subfig` package.

(The framelines in the following image indicate the edges of the text block.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{elsarticle} % remove 'demo' option in real doc
    %% preamble reduced the bare minimum
    \usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph1}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph2}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph3}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Three simple graphs}\label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A MWE, after removing all not relevant packages, and use correct syntax for subfigures (see @leandriis comments), is

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subfig} % <----

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
         \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            }\hfil
         \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
             }\hfil
         \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for stripping the preamble down to its bare minimum. :-)

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! And +1 for you for use `subcaption` package!

Comment: ...and I vote positive all :-)

Comment: +1 all it's on the house :D